# Labeling vertices by number in Graph: Getting text to display at the right size

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, style

Minor aesthetic question here. I was playing around with `Graph`'s and decided to render a cute-looking family of directed graphs, with the vertices being the number associated with the vertex. Here is an example with number of nodes $n=200$ (right-click and open in a new tab to see at proper resolution):

```
n = 200;
Graph[Table[i -> Mod[30 i, n, 1], {i, n}], ImageSize -> 1280, 
 VertexShape -> Table[i -> i, {i, n}], VertexSize -> 1, 
 VertexStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Green, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

It looks fine. Now let's try $n=5$:

```
n = 5;
Graph[Table[i -> Mod[30 i, n, 1], {i, n}], ImageSize -> 1280, 
 VertexShape -> Table[i -> i, {i, n}], VertexSize -> 1, 
 VertexStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Green, Background -> Black]
```

[image]

The vertex labels are gigantic and distort the figure to make it unreadable. Fine, let's just set `VertexSize -> Automatic`:

[image]

Much better. Let's try using `VertexSize -> Automatic` for the $n=200$ case once more:

[image]

The three-digit labels are unreadable, because `Automatic` does not appear to correctly scale them, and so it only displays the first digit and cuts off the rest with a `...`.

Is there an automatic way (other than `VertexSize -> Automatic`) to make text vertices show up as the right size without being truncated?

Comment: Renders fine for me, 9.0.1, Windows, using `VertexSize->Automatic`

Comment: I would need of this software to generate such random numbers on each vertice. Please , what is the name of software?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/53462)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/53462)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can see the same problem in *Mathematica* version 8.04. What cured the display problem was the explicit specification of a `VertexShapeFunction` as follows:

```
n = 200;
Graph[Table[i -> Mod[30 i, n, 1], {i, n}], ImageSize -> 1280, 
 VertexShape -> Table[i -> i, {i, n}], VertexSize -> Automatic, 
 VertexStyle -> White, EdgeStyle -> Green, Background -> Black, 
 VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[#2, #1] &)]
```

[image: pic]

You can add this last option for all `Graph`s instead of specifying it in every instance, by doing this:

```
SetOptions[Graph, VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[#2, #1] &)];
```

Then your original code with `VertexSize -> Automatic` should appear without the cut-off labels.

Comment: `VertexShape->"Name"` will work as well. The explicit Table specification is not necessary.

Comment: @FrancoisVanderseypen Thanks, you're right - I just copied that from the original question.

Answer (score 2):

You could play with `GraphLayout`:

```
n=200;
Graph[Table[i->Mod[30 i,n,1],{i,n}],ImageSize->1280,VertexShape->Table[i->i,    
  {i,n}],VertexSize->1,VertexStyle->White,EdgeStyle->Green,
  Background->Black,GraphLayout->"BalloonEmbedding"]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the post. This doesn't exactly answer my question, since setting $n=5$ in your code still gives the same problem; I was mainly looking for something which renders correctly for all $n$. That said, my issue is a minor aesthetic one, and I can always do the vertex sizes manually if needed, so if no one else posts anything I'll accept this answer. I tend to use the `SpringElectricalEmbedding` method, I hadn't seen the `BalloonEmbedding` you used, seems like an interesting alternative.