# Optimal Size labelling for saving Graph on File

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, labeling, pdf-format

I looked at  [Labeling vertices by number in Graph: Getting text to display at the right size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/labeling-vertices-by-number-in-graph-getting-text-to-display-at-the-right-size) but did not find an answer for my case.

I want to save a table of graphs on file, pdf or PNG, for a presentation.

In my Notebook, I can see the table of graph like this:

[image]

I tried with Graph options:

```
VertexLabels -> "Name",
VertexSize -> Automatic
```

but still labels get clogged.

I can manually stretch the output size to make it readable, like this:

[image]

However, when I save it, the size of labels get not consistent with what I see.

Is there a way to automatically adjust the output file dimensions in function of the size of labels and number of vertexes, so that there is no overlapping and graph is readable?

An alternative solution, it can also be change the size of text in function of a centrality measure. I can do it in my notebook, but it is challenging on saved file for some text get rendered supersmall (that is, on pdf, you gotta zoom it quite much).

Comment: Can you show the saved version to compare?